# Как получить объект из вложенного цикла с помощью stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, optional

Есть xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns3:WSConsumerDictionaryInfoGetResponse xmlns:ns3="http://WSConsumerDictionaryInfo11" xmlns:ns2="http://WSCommonTypes10">
        <response>
            <outCommonParms>
                <outCommonParmsExt>
                    <name>logUID</name>
                    <value>1234</value>
                </outCommonParmsExt>
            </outCommonParms>
            <outParms>
                <dictionaries>
                    <dictionary>
                        <code>OKP-123</code>
                        <codeCategory>OKOPF</codeCategory>
                        <bCode>75203</bCode>
                        <name>test</name>
                        <note>BHPF</note>
                        <hasChildren>0</hasChildren>
                        <open>2018-04-07T07:32:44</open>
                        <close>9999-12-31T23:59:59</close>
                        <attributes>
                            <attribute>
                                <field>isPublicSectorEntity</field>
                                <value>1</value>
                                <open>0001-01-01T00:00:00</open>
                                <close>9999-12-31T23:59:59</close>
                            </attribute>
                        </attributes>
                    </dictionary>
                </dictionaries>
            </outParms>
        </response>
    </ns3:WSConsumerDictionaryInfoGetResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Где есть список dictionaries в котором есть список attributes
нужно найти attribute у которого

> field = isPublicSectorEntity

и взять его все остальные значения (value, open, close)

Пытаюсь сделать это с помощью стрима:

```
wsConsumerDictionaryInfoGetOutParms.getDictionaries().getDictionary().stream()
                .filter(dictionary -> dictionary.getAttributes().getAttribute().stream()
                        .filter(attribute -> attribute.getField().equalsIgnoreCase(BUDGET_ORGANIZATION_FLAG))
                        .findFirst());
```

Но что то идет не так) Я примерно понимаю что но как исправить не могу понять.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутренним фильтром можно найти и взять нужный объект проверив field но вот как вернуть его ведь он находится во внутреннем цикле?

Хотелось бы как то вот так:

```
        String budgetFlag = "";
        for(WSConsumerDictionaryInfoDictionary r : wsConsumerDictionaryInfoGetOutParms.getDictionaries().getDictionary()){
            for(WSConsumerDictionaryInfoDictionaryAttribute t : r.getAttributes().getAttribute()){
                if(t.getField().equalsIgnoreCase(BUDGET_ORGANIZATION_FLAG)){
                    budgetFlag = t.getValue();            
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Думаю ошибка в том, что метод `filter` принимает предикат, т.е. ему нужно булевое значение, а метод `getFirst()` возвращает тип `Optional<T>`, а не искомую строку (Хотя это, думаю, ты и сам понял). Если твой метод с потоками правильный, то в конце после вызова метода `findFirst()` попробуй вызвать метод `get()`. А вообще, какая необходимость делать это через `Stream`? Если итерация выглядит читабельнее, то лучше ее и использовать

Comment: После фильтра остаётся стрим с данными, которые удовлетворяют фильтру. С этим стримом вы можете работать дальше. В фильтре findFirst() не нужен.

Comment: два вложенных цикла - признак того, что вам  нужен flatMap. представьте себи лист вложенный в лист. когда вы вызовите стрим у листа, то получите листы в потоке. именно в этом случае нужно вызвать flatMap, после вызова которого в поток попадут данные из вложенного листа.